# django json response and ajax call

Tags: jquery, django

Kindly let me know how to consume django api method using jquery ajax call, because when I try to access directly URL am getting response, however when I send request using jquery ajax call, it goes to error function.

**Dajango code:**

```
def rain_api(request):
data = {}
data['test'] = 'hello'
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type = "application/json")
```

**JQuery code:**

```
requestURL="http://ipaddress/raindata";

$.ajax({
            url: requestURL,
              dataType: "json", 

            success:function(result){
                console.log(result)

            },
            done:function(result){
                 console.log(result)
            },
            error:function(error){
                console.log(error);

            }

        })
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: any empty string, it just call error function, no output displayed on the console

Comment: how does your xhr request look like,what response code does it have?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code. I tested it and it worked fine. What does your `urls.py` look like?

Comment: @skoll url(r'^raindata/$', rain_api)

Comment: @madalinivascu am getting 200

Comment: @niran that means your ajax is successful,

Comment: @madalinivascu but asyc call should call success event instead of error event of xhr

Comment: How do you know which event it's calling? They all have exactly the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
 $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: 'http://ipaddress/raindata',
               processData: true,
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function(data ) {

                 console.log("Success")


                   }
               });
    }
```